# Sorting a dictionary according to the key

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, dictionary

I have made a dictionary with two lists in Google Earth Engine and I want to sort them according to the "xVals" in the code. By default, the order is improper. I need it in ascending order of "xVals".

```
var xAxis = ['B2','B3','B4','B8','B11','B12'];
var xVals = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

var dict = ee.Dictionary.fromLists(xAxis, xVals);
print(dict);
```

Result:

[image]

It should be B2, B3, B4, B8, B11, B12.

Comment: If the sort algorithm doesn't have a numerically-aware sort option, you need to either reformat the keys to have fixed width (padding with zeros) or split them into alpha and numeric components and sort on two terms.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as a sort order in a dictionary.  Keys are always displayed alphanumerically, but even that is just for display purposes.  There is no order.